# Using Ruby to find a file with changing directory

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to find a file in which the directory will change its name with upcoming versions, so an example could be that it is located under `/opt/here/test-1.44/bin/progname` and will follow the format same time.

I'm looking to do something like `if File.exist?("/opt/here/test-*/bin/progname")` but is that the correct format?  When searching around I'm also seeing references to using `Dir`, so would it be something like `if Dir['/opt/here/*'.select { |f| f =~ /progname/} then` ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me.. Could you be more specific ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: I'm basically looking to see if some file exists, but when it gets installed it goes into a directory where the name changes with each version.  I don't know what version it will be looking for, so I need to integrate some sort of wildcard to take that into account.  Both `/opt/here/test-0.3/bin/progname` and `/opt/here/test-1.4/bin/progname` are valid directories.

Comment: And you do not like my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
Dir.glob("/opt/here/test-*/bin/progname").empty?
```

Use `any?` instead of `empty?` if you want `true` when there is such file.

Comment: Hi!  Sorry just saw your answer.  Yes I think this is what I'm looking for, I had some of the syntax confused thank you!